# How do I extend LUKS partition to fill the whole logical volume of 2 disks on LVM?

Tags: partition, lvm, encryption, luks

I have added a second disk to my LVM system. I created a physical volume there, added it to the volume group of ubuntu, 'vgubuntu', extended logical volume to fill the whole disk. How do I extend the `LUKS` system partition to fill the whole logical volume? Here's more info provided by `pvdisplay`, `vgdisplay` and `lvdisplay`:

```
  --- Physical volume ---
  PV Name               /dev/mapper/nvme0n1p3_crypt
  VG Name               vgubuntu
  PV Size               <464.53 GiB / not usable 0   
  Allocatable           NO
  PE Size               4.00 MiB
  Total PE              118919
  Free PE               0
  Allocated PE          118919
  PV UUID               DwO3R1-DeRo-c83D-qx5F-xjC5-icXG-x3j28i
 
  --- Physical volume ---
  PV Name               /dev/nvme1n1p1
  VG Name               vgubuntu
  PV Size               <476.94 GiB / not usable 0   
  Allocatable           yes (but full)
  PE Size               4.00 MiB
  Total PE              122096
  Free PE               0
  Allocated PE          122096
  PV UUID               9UyJR4-m0G9-sYPG-BBkW-2WEg-TBdR-DAj0u3



root@omen15:~# vgdisplay
  --- Volume group ---
  VG Name               vgubuntu
  System ID             
  Format                lvm2
  Metadata Areas        2
  Metadata Sequence No  8
  VG Access             read/write
  VG Status             resizable
  MAX LV                0
  Cur LV                2
  Open LV               2
  Max PV                0
  Cur PV                2
  Act PV                2
  VG Size               941.46 GiB
  PE Size               4.00 MiB
  Total PE              241015
  Alloc PE / Size       241015 / 941.46 GiB
  Free  PE / Size       0 / 0   
  VG UUID               ANNTFf-p9hU-O4R3-jwDQ-bZhP-v8tm-hVL8Fn


root@omen15:~# lvdisplay
  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Path                /dev/vgubuntu/root
  LV Name                root
  VG Name                vgubuntu
  LV UUID                rxnIOU-yNg2-ythJ-Dz5V-N3Sr-X7DQ-WzbUUF
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Creation host, time ubuntu, 2021-07-24 17:25:39 +0300
  LV Status              available
  # open                 1
  LV Size                <940.51 GiB
  Current LE             240770
  Segments               2
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  - currently set to     256
  Block device           253:1
 
  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Path                /dev/vgubuntu/swap_1
  LV Name                swap_1
  VG Name                vgubuntu
  LV UUID                MOvhEP-64w3-wHHO-wmDh-YkSU-XARL-7hRQIf
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Creation host, time ubuntu, 2021-07-24 17:25:39 +0300
  LV Status              available
  # open                 2
  LV Size                980.00 MiB
  Current LE             245
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  - currently set to     256
  Block device           253:2
```

And here's what `df -h` prints:

```
root@omen15:~# df -h
Filesystem                 Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
tmpfs                      1.6G  2.1M  1.6G   1% /run
/dev/mapper/vgubuntu-root  925G  7.3G  871G   1% /
tmpfs                      7.6G   12M  7.6G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs                      5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs                      4.0M     0  4.0M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/nvme0n1p2             705M  251M  403M  39% /boot
/dev/nvme0n1p1             511M  5.3M  506M   2% /boot/efi
tmpfs                      1.6G  2.0M  1.6G   1% /run/user/1000
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have LUKS configured on the PV level so "under" your LVM setup so unfortunately you need to start over -- your PV must be encrypted you can't "extend" the existing LUKS/dm-crypt device to the second disk. The structure should look like *disk -> partition -> LUKS -> PV -> VG -> LV* (it is possible to configure encryption on the LV level but your existing configuration is encrypted on the PV level).

So you need to shrink your `root` LV back, remove your newly created PV from `vgubuntu` and then create LUKS on `nvme1n1p1` (`cryptsetup luksFormat /dev/nvme1n1p1`), unlock it (`cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/nvme1n1p1 nvme1n1p1_crypt`) and use `/dev/mapper/nvme1n1p1_crypt` as the second PV. You'll also need to add the new LUKS device to `/etc/crypttab`.